# Change True/False value to discrete value in pandas dataframe with np.where()

Tags: python, pandas, contains, assign, extract

I am trying to assign a state name to a list of university names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'College': pd.Series(['University of Michigan', 'University of Florida', 'Iowa State'])})
State = ['Michigan', 'Iowa']
df['State'] = np.where(df['College'].str.contains('|'.join(State)),
    'state','--')
```

I would like to replace the "state" value that appears when there is a match with the actual name of the state. Example: University of Michigan -> Michigan (rather than "state"). Ultimately, "State" will have all 50 states so I can't write 50 "np.where" statements for each state name.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `str.extract` here, instead of `np.where`:

```
In [290]: df['State'] = df['College'].str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(State)), expand=True)

In [291]: df
Out[291]: 
                  College     State
0  University of Michigan  Michigan
1   University of Florida       NaN
2              Iowa State      Iowa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
States = [
            'Washington' 'Wisconsin' 'West Virginia' 'Florida' 'Wyoming'
            'New Hampshire' 'New Jersey' 'New Mexico' 'National' 'North Carolina'
            'North Dakota' 'Nebraska' 'New York' 'Rhode Island' 'Nevada' 'Guam'
            'Colorado' 'California' 'Georgia' 'Connecticut' 'Oklahoma' 'Ohio' 'Kansas'
            'South Carolina' 'Kentucky' 'Oregon' 'South Dakota' 'Delaware'
            'District of Columbia' 'Hawaii' 'Puerto Rico' 'Texas' 'Louisiana'
            'Tennessee' 'Pennsylvania' 'Virginia' 'Virgin Islands' 'Alaska' 'Alabama'
            'American Samoa' 'Arkansas' 'Vermont' 'Illinois' 'Indiana' 'Iowa'
            'Arizona' 'Idaho' 'Maine' 'Maryland' 'Massachusetts' 'Utah' 'Missouri'
            'Minnesota' 'Michigan' 'Montana' 'Northern Mariana Islands' 'Mississippi'
]

state_str = '|'.join(States)
df.update(df.College.str.extract(r'(?P<State>{})'.format(state_str), expand=True))

df
```

[image]